# How to get average value

Tags: matlab

In the program below, I want to change the value of `Trial` and want to run it for a thousand times, counting the occurrences of `N` in `D` in each trial (*i.e* iteration).

```
N     = 10;
B     = eye(N);
C     = zeros(1,N);
p     = [0.1 0.2 0.4];
count = 1;
Trial = 1;

for t = 1:Trial
    for q = 1:numel(p)
        for ii=1:N      
            X = B;
            X(ii, rand(size(p))<p(q)) = 0;

            A = max(bsxfun(@minus, X,C), 0);
            [~,idx] = max(A(sum(A,2)==1,:), [], 2);
            if ~isempty(idx)
                C(idx) = 1; 
            end
        end

        D(count,:) = sum(C);
        count = count+1; 

    end
end
```

I know how to count the occurrences of `N` in `D`. The problem is that for `Trial = 2`, array `D` becomes 6x1, but I want it to always remain 3x1 in each iteration. How do I do that?

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your code.

Comment: @Dan -corrected,Please check.

Comment: `D(count,:)=sum(C)` is incorrect if you want to keep D a certain size. You continue to increment count, so D will continue to grow in size.

Answer (score 1):

The `count` value seems to have no purpose since you want D to remain `3-by-1`.  The easy fix is to change the assignment to `D` to:

```
D(q,:) = sum(C);
```

since `q` iterates from 1 to `numel(p)` (i.e. 3), and is thus already the counter you want.